# toStandardDate is not a function: How to correctly use Neo4j's DateTime in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, neo4j

```js
// I've tried both imports
import { DateTime } from "neo4j-driver";
//import {DateTime} from 'neo4j-driver-core/lib/temporal-types.js'

export type LABELLED = Relationship<
  Integer,
  {
    created: DateTime;
  }
>;

// Later I'm using it like this;

created: pageResult.r.properties.created.toStandardDate().toDateString(),
```

The run time error is this;

TypeError: pageResult.r.properties.created.toStandardDate is not a function

Any pointers are appriciated

Comment: Have you investigated what `pageResult.r.properties.created` is?

Comment: Yes, it's in my own type LABELLED you see above. The pageResult.r properties is what you see above in the exported type. It's a DateTime directly from neo4j-driver.

Comment: You should still verify the class of `created` in the query result. Driver query results can surprise you.